# React object iteration

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React. Can someone tell me, why this works:

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
                {this._persons.map( function (p, i) {
                    return <Person name={p.name} age={p.age} />
                })}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

but this not:

```
getPersons() {
        this._persons.map(function (p, i) {
            console.log(i);
            return <Person name={p.name} age={p.age} />
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Hello, React!</h1>
                {this.getPersons()}
            </div>
        )
    }
```

The map function is definalty used because I get the result from the log function, but the Person component will not be rendert.

Answer (score 3):

You never actually return anything from `getPersons`. Therefore there is nothing to render. You just need to return the result of your call to `map`:

```
getPersons() {
  return this._persons.map(function (p, i) {
    console.log(i);
    return <Person name={p.name} age={p.age} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: how should I write it then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result of the `getPersons` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `getPersons()` method just returning anything.

```
getPersons() {
    return this._persons.map(function (p, i) {
        console.log(i);
        return <Person name={p.name} age={p.age} />
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats it